# Java streams, take data from 2 lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the 2 following lists, I am trying to print (by Java Stream) the average and the name of each course.
The output of my code right now gives me only the first course's name and sum but I don't get of the other courses

How can I fix my code? This is my code:

```
courses.stream()
       .forEach(action -> System.out.println(action.getName()+" "
                    +students.stream()
                             .mapToDouble(f->f.getGrades().stream()
                                     .filter(predicate->predicate.getCourse()
                                             .getName()
                                             .equals(action.getName()))
                                     .findFirst()
                                     .get()
                                     .getValue())
                             .sum() ));`
```

This is the list:

```
     List<Student> students = new LinkedList<Student>() {{
        add(
                new Student("Moshe", 21, 1, new LinkedList<Grade>() {{
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 30).findFirst().get(), 67));
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 32).findFirst().get(), 89));
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 35).findFirst().get(), 67));
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 37).findFirst().get(), 89));
                }})
        );
        add(
                new Student("Yossi", 26, 2, new LinkedList<Grade>() {{
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 30).findFirst().get(), 100));
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 32).findFirst().get(), 67));
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 35).findFirst().get(), 89));
                }})
        );
        add(
                new Student("Natasha", 30, 3, new LinkedList<Grade>() {{
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 30).findFirst().get(), 67));
                    add(new Grade(courses.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == 37).findFirst().get(), 80));

                }})
        );
    }};

   List<Course> courses = new LinkedList<Course>() {{
        add(new Course(30, "Data Structures", 3.5f));
        add(new Course(32, "Geometry", 6));
        add(new Course(35, "Algebra", 2.5f));
        add(new Course(37, "English", 7));
    }};
```

Comment: Wonder if you could [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think this is a question where anybody wanting to help would like to reproduce first.

Answer (score 4):

Your code throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` from the `get` method that you call after `findFirst()`. This happens when `findFirst()` returns an empty `Optional`.

Why does that happen in your code? For each student in your stream of students you make a stream of grades that you filter by course name to get only the grade for the course we are currently summing for. If the student in question doesn’t have a grade for the course in question, all grades are filtered out from the stream, and `findFirst()` returns an empty `Optional`.

As you said, the code does print the result for the first course, though:

```
Data Structures 234.0
```

The code works for this course because all students have got it, so there will never be an empty stream of grades. For the next course, Geometry, there will because Natasha hasn’t got a grade in Geometry. So here the exception happens.

The solution is not that far from the code you had:

```
    courses.stream()
            .forEach(course -> System.out.println(course.getName() + ' '
                    + students.stream()
                        .flatMap(student -> student.getGrades()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(grade -> grade.getCourse()
                                                    .getName()
                                                    .equals(course.getName())))
                        .mapToDouble(Grade::getValue)
                        .sum()));
```

The new element I have introduced is a `flatMap()` operation in the stream of students. The argument to `flatMap()` produces a stream of grades, possibly empty. `flatMap()` produces a stream of the elements from those streams of grades. If a student hasn’t got a grade in a course, it just means no grade element is supplied to the stream. Now we can map all the grades we got to doubles and sum them.

The output is

```
Data Structures 234.0
Geometry 156.0
Algebra 156.0
English 169.0
```

BTW, shouldn’t your `Course` class have an `equals` method? Then `grade -> grade.getCourse().getName().equals(course.getName())` could be simplified to `grade -> grade.getCourse().equals(course)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Grades has a link to Course you can use just one stream.
Take all grades from all students and then put it on a map.
Where key - course name, value is sum.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = students.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> s.getGrades().stream())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(g -> g.getCourse().getName(),
                            Grade::getValue, 
                           (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue + newValue));
    map.entrySet().forEach(es -> System.out.println(es.getKey() + " " + es.getValue()));
```